# GetBytes in C# not returning correct value

Tags: c#, sql-server, varbinary

I have a method that execute stored procedure and returns values of that stored procedure. I have a VIN that in SQL is in `VarBinary` type. I am not sure what can I use to get the value.

This is my code:

```
    // Get Customer Product By CustomerID
    public Model.CustomerProduct Get_CustomerProduct(int Customer_ID)
    {
        Model.CustomerProduct model = null;

        string myConnection = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[connectionName].ToString();
        SqlDatabase db = new SqlDatabase(myConnection);
        int bufferSize = 100;                   

        byte[] outByte = new byte[bufferSize];  
        using (DbCommand command = db.GetStoredProcCommand("Get_Customer_Product"))
        {
            db.AddInParameter(command, "Customer_ID", DbType.Int32, Customer_ID);

            var result = db.ExecuteReader(command);

            try
            {
                if (result.FieldCount == 0)
                    model = null;
                else
                {
                    result.Read();
                    model = new Model.CustomerProduct()
                    {
                       Product_Name = result.GetString(2)
                      ,VIN =result.GetBytes(3,0,outByte,0,bufferSize)   // this return me wrong 



                    };
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {


            }
            return model;
        }
    }
```

My problem is this line:

```
     VIN =result.GetBytes(3,0,outByte,0,bufferSize)
```

This is returning 44 however the value that is suppose to return is:

0x00D1CCE9771AE7554D479F7B93A45611010000004158D130E5097EF2924DEC4C6255E5BAF4C8EF4C2AC2A8FD9F29295F41DA3550123C6C4575788F5E6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [GetBytes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getbytes(v=vs.110).aspx) method returns the number of bytes it has written to the array, not the bytes themselves. Have a look at the contents of `outByte` and you should find your data there.

I would also suggest you first call `GetBytes` with a null buffer. This will cause it to return the length of the field, allowing you to size your buffer properly:

```
int len = result.GetBytes( 3, 0, null, 0, 0 );
byte[] buf = new byte[len];
result.GetBytes( 3, 0, buf, 0, buf.Length );

model = new Model.CustomerProduct()
{
    Product_Name = result.GetString(2),
    VIN = buf
};
```

If the code you have now runs, you most likely will have to change the type of `VIN` to a `byte[]` too.

Comment: thanks but I will get all 00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 for that.

Comment: What type is the field in the db?

Comment: the type in db is VarBinary(500)

Comment: Try simply `(byte[])result[3]`.

Answer (score 2):

GetBytes returns number of bytes read. Since you are assigning Getbytes return value to VIN , you see number of bytes read in VIN.

Instead you must read from the output buffer i.e. in your case outByte will have the bytes that are read.